# Merging columns in dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have 2 dataframes :

```
df1   folder_name   name
    0   a1          aa
    1   b1          bb


df2    name        icon
    0   aa          aa
    1   bb          bb
    3   aadoq       aadoq
    4   bbaddd      bbaddd
```

Now i want to match the pattern of column name and then merge

desired output:

```
df   folder_name    name    icon
    0   a1          aa       aa
    1   b1          bb       bb
    3   a1         aadoq    aadoq
    4   b1         bbaddd   bbaddd
```

actual output:

```
df   folder_name    name    icon
        0   a1          aa       aa
        1   b1          bb       bb
        3   NAN         aadoq    aadoq
        4   NAN         bbaddd   bbaddd
```

So if name column of df1 matches name column of df2 then also my merge should work . Is there any way for getting this

I tried doing pd.merge(df1,df2,on='name',how='right')
but it gives me NAN in icon where name is aadoq and bbaddd . I want if name is aadoq which contains aa so it should pick aa as icon

Comment: You could merge and drop duplicates? You just need to marry up the column names

Comment: my requirement is like if aadoq matches withh aa so icon should not be NAN

Comment: How do you know that `aadoq` has `folder_name` `aaa`? Or that `bbaddd` has `folder_name` `bbb`? The `name` implies `folder_name` just based off the first two letters? Or is it something else?

Comment: yes , name column matches in df2 if name column string contains any string of name column in df1 then it should take that folder name

Comment: Is there any reason to not merge on 'icon' and 'name' columns ? Works on your example.

Comment: Then how do you know that `bbaddd` maps to `bbb`? It contains both `a` and `b`.

Comment: yes icon can be different value ....i just wrote it as example

Comment: no just the starting string should match .....

Comment: This is a basic merge problem. See the duplicate for info on how to call df.merge.

Comment: @coldspeed I don't think it is. I don't think the OP even needs to merge. He/she simply wants to derive `folder_name` directly from `name` (as far as I can tell).

Comment: yes. I dont mind using something else than merge

Comment: Can you suggest some alternative?

Comment: @MattMessersmith Perhaps, since it is a single column, more performant alternatives with map exist (also in the linked dupe ...;-))

Comment: @ayushgupta Click on the linked dupe and search for "Merging only a single column from one of the DataFrames".

Comment: @Thanks coldspeed really enjoyed your post, taught me a lot.

Comment: Or...just do `df2['folder_name'] = df2['name'].apply(lambda x: x[0]*3)`...

Comment: why *3? string suffix can be of any length

Comment: cn i use any regex here?

Comment: @MattMessersmith it actually works somehow. Thanks . Let me test that

Comment: no it does not . Folder name can be anything else as well that was just an exampe

Comment: It works because what you're trying to do is fundamentally not a merge. `x[0]` is the first character of the `name`. Then, `x[0]*3` is that character repeated 3 times. That's how you're asking to generate the `folder_name` as far as I can tell. Again, it's not a merge, and `df1` appears to be irrelevant...

Comment: There's a better way you could do it by saying if `name` starts with "blah" then map that to the `folder_name` in `df1` that also starts with "blah" (which is a bit more general and probably what you want).

Comment: how should i do that . Folder name is just an example it can be anything not related to name column. see i have modified my question for better understanding

Comment: You'll have to appeal to @coldspeed to unlock the question, but I think his link does contain a (roundabout) answer to your question. I'm not going to spend time with a closed question though, sorry.